# flow rate in a circular pipe

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, fluid-dynamics

If the velocity distribution of a fluid flowing through a pipe is known,
the flow rate Q can be calculated by $Q=\int vdA$, where v is the velocity and A is the area
pipeline cross section. Consider a circular pipe of $A=\pi r^2$ and $dA=2\pi r$
[image]

So, we have: $$Q=\int_0^r v(2\pi r)dr$$ Where r is a radial distance measured outward from the center of the pipe. If the distribution
speed is given by: $$v=2(1-\frac{r}{r_0})^{\frac{1}{6}}$$

Where $r_0$ is the total radius (in this case 3 cm), calculate Q.

my attempt:

With the information I have, I wrote the integral as follows $$Q= \int_0^3 2(1-\frac{r}{3})^{\frac{1}{6}}2\pi r dr$$
Since the pipe is circular I wrote R = 3 cm and $r_0$ = 3cm. But I'm not sure if this is the correct way to write the integral, I don't know if I have to change the 3 cm to meters or if it doesn't matter. Any help that clarifies if I wrote the integral correctly, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: $$\int_0^r \; v(2\pi r) \,\mathrm{d}r$$ has two incompatible uses of the variable $r$, the radius of the tube.  If $r$ is the constant radius of the tube, how does $r$ vary from $0$ to $r$?  What are the units of $v$ (or of $Q$)?

Comment: @EricTowers That's what has me confused, I was thinking that r must be constant so $$Q=\int_0^r 2(1-r/3)^{1/6}2\pi r dr$$ But I'm also not sure if it should be written like this

Comment: Once we establish $r$ is the radius of the pipe, we must use some other variable as the dummy variable (alt., formal parameter) of the integral.  For instance,$$\int_0^r v(u) \cdot 2 \pi u \,\mathrm{d}u \text{,}$$ where $u$ is the radius of the annular shell of circumference $2 \pi u$ and thickness $\Delta u$ in the Riemann sum whose limit we take to get this integral...

Comment: @EricTowers more specifically the integral will remain as $$\int_0^3 2(1-\frac{u}{3})^{\frac{1}{6}}2 \pi u du$$ ?

Comment: Sure.  But until we know the units of $v$ or $Q$, we cannot answer your question about conversion of units.  As written, the "$2$" in $v = 2 \left( \dots \right)^{1/6}$ has unspecified units (because the expression abbreviated as "$\dots$" is unitless).

Comment: @EricTowers the exercise does not specify it, I suppose it should be done in cm

Comment: @RafaelBello Incorrect unit can make a world of difference! Thankfully it is just an exercise, though badly written up. In any case, if the exercise does not specify, assume a unit and specify in the beginning of your answer.